# how would i find the radius with the chord length and the chord distance to the circumference

Tags: geometry

[image: example]

I have the chord length QR and segment VT lets say VT is 4 and QR is 36 and i know that the radius is perpendicular to the chord, with only this information how would I find the radius of the circle?

Comment: You have a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).  The Wikipedia article give you everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia article on the circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle):

> The [chord theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Theorems)
> states that if two chords, $CD$ and $EB$, intersect at $A$, then
> $AC\times AD = AB\times AE$.

So let $P$ be the point on the circumference opposite $T$; now the theorem says that $PV\times VT=(\frac12 QR)^2$. This gives you a linear equation in $r$, the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Let the radius of the circle be $x$. Then QV=$18$ cm (WHY?). Now QT = $x$ because QT is also radius. We know VT=$4$. So we get OVQ as a right angled triangle in this form.

[image]

Can you find $x$ by pythagoras theorem or rather the radius of the circle?